# What configuration in SQL would change the redirect URL after clientlogin.php?

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

What configuration in SQL would change the redirect URL after clientlogin.php?

I tried to edit the SystemURL but it is not affecting the redirect after login.

Comment: I think SQL configuration has nothing to do with redirection

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand what you do. 
SQL requests and authentication hasn't been coupled.

You have to do your authentication system and inside it use SQL ORM or service.
if the user has the requirement so you can redirect him.

Comment: There's no way for me to know, WHMCS is encrypted